# PositiveSSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

My client bought a PositiveSSL Certificate, and he gave me 2 files, crt and ca-bundle.

How can I install these files to the ubuntu server and make the https protocol work?

FYI, I'm using nginx.

Any clue?

Comment: You also need the private key used to create the certificate.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but he didn't give me the key file, he said his previous developer created the certificate and he didn't know any details about the process, looks like he's a non technical person.

Comment: His certificate files were installed on cPanel, any clue how to retrieve it from cPanel?

Comment: his current httpd (apache, nginx, whatever) will have a config file that points to the key file, you can ignore cpanel as long as you have access to the server.

Comment: If it's too hard to retrieve the old key, and if it's not an EV certificate or something otherwise fancy, I'd suggest to simply move them to a free letencrypt certificate instead. Automate it and you'll never have to renew certificates on a deadline again.

Answer (score 0):

**key file**

First off: you need the secret key as well, from the extensions on the filenames you are missing that file.

**ngnix**

nginx expects a chained certificate, but that's easy enough to create:

```
$ cd /path/to
$ cat www.example.com.crt ca-bundle.crt > example.bundle.crt
```

While at it create the Diffie–Hellman parameters:

```
$ openssl dhparam -out dh4096.pem 4096
```

You need to add a few statements to the appropriate place in your configuration file(s).
It's the server block that needs something like this:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    server_name  www.example.com ;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/example.bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/example.key;

    # take care: a single add_header *will* wipe all the inherited ones!
    # HSTS (be careful, this is irreversible!) 
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
}
```

Something like this can be added to the http block:

```
http {
    #ssl parameters (certificates in the virtual servers)
    ssl_dhparam /path/to/dh4096.pem;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:!DSS:!DES";
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
}
```

[that way you only need to maintain that stuff once for all virtual servers, is also ok to add it in the server blocks that use ssl]

More info:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

**Test it**

Free tests are available, e.g. this one: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/
Fix it to make sure you're set at a high enough rating.